# Avoid further decoders loading only .png data using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, png

I am trying to avoid searching, loading or instantiating any other decoders than the [png-Decoder](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/a332509e02bdd00c1f8b8ffdb4ba47fa7aade053/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_png.hpp#L54) when an image is loaded using opencv's [cv::imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) or similar functionalities to get a `cv::Mat` from a .png-file.

However, [cv::imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) and [cv::imdecode](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e) do both [load several other decoders](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/14e4a10312ff12d8085d8dc67d5d834b93c4361f/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp#L222). Thus I looked up what Decoder-class was instantiated to decode png-data and tried to instantiate and use it in my own png-loader function. This was not successful since the class [PngDecoder](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/a332509e02bdd00c1f8b8ffdb4ba47fa7aade053/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_png.hpp#L54) utilized by the original functions is not accessible from user code.

The code processing the images depends on opencv. I thought about libpng or so, but I wanted to stick to opencv functionalities if possible.

Unfortunately, there is now way for me to compile opencv myself so compiler-flags aren't an option for me at the moment.

Now I was wondering whether any of you guys does know:

- Is there a way to tell [cv::imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) or [cv::imdecode](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e) which decoders to load during runtime?
- Is there any way to access the specific decoder classes that I didn't found, yet?
- Is there any known reasons why those classes are hidden from the users in the first place?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
To avoid further misunderstandings I want to explain the reason for my wish to avoid unnecessary decoders to be loaded:

I compiled my project with gcc's thread sanitizer which informed me about a lock-order-inversion causing a possible deadlock, which matches to some runtime observations I made. The Stacktrace and some code-reduction to determine the responsible code  suggested that a `cv::imread`-call, or more specific a lock of a mutex inside gdal-library within OpenCV code, was the reason for this:

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: lock-order-inversion (potential deadlock) (pid=174547)
  Cycle in lock order graph: M456973885219073664 (0x000000000000) => M458095095759505664 (0x000000000000) => M456973885219073664

  Mutex M458095095759505664 acquired here while holding mutex M456973885219073664 in main thread:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4148 (libtsan.so.0+0x4db3a)
    #1 CPLAcquireMutex <null> (libgdal.so.28+0x1074086)
```

I further investigated how this could happen or how to avoid this. It turned out that on every `cv::imread`-call gdal dependend decoders were loaded. This brought me to my original question here: How to avoid the loading of unnecessary decoders while loading/decoding images using OpenCV?

Comment: May I ask why you want any other decoder (than that for PNG) to be excluded?

Comment: You could check beforehand whether the file to load is a PNG file. For this, just open the file in a stream and check the first few bytes for the [magic code of PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) (which is `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a` according to the linked Wikipedia article).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat ofcourse you can. There is some locking code at least within the decoder for geo-tagged images comming from gdal which is used by opencv. I suspect this to cause problems since a tsan trace points to a gdal mutex. Other decoders might come with similar load that I want to avoid. I am currently working on png only.

I guess checking for .png-content will let me alone with the decodeing so just lookup some image file content wouldn't help.

Comment: I'm not common with OpenCV. As you stated you don't intend to dig in the guts of OpenCV too deep, the check I recommended above might be a reasonable and cheap workaround. ;-)

Comment: Not sure whether there was a mis-understanding. I didn't recommend to do the decoding on your own. (Or was that what you are actually asking for?) I recommend to ensure that the file path does in fact address a PNG file (by checking its magic code) before you hand over the file path to `cv::imread()`. You could also check for the file suffix, of course, but this can be fooled quite easy. The doc. you linked states explicitly that OpenCV decodes the files according to their magic code - ignoring any (maybe wrong) file suffix in the file path...

Comment: Yeah the problem is to tell OpenCV to not load all the encoders for the supported formats but only for the one I'm looking for. So you are right on the check i guess, but `cd::imread` and `cv::imdecode` will still load all possible decoders despite of my knowledge of a specific file to load.

Comment: Isn't it your code which calls `cv::imread()`? If you check a file path beforehand in your code and call `cv::imread()` only if your check is satisfied... Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: Both `cv::imread` and `cv::imdecoed` will always call findDecoder which instantiated all kinds possible decoders. This is hard coded behavior in those functions. It doesn't check any thing beforehand and as I understand the docs and implementation there no way to tell them to do otherwise. That's where my question begins: is there a way to do so that i didn't encountered yet?

Comment: A last desperate try... If *your* code doesn't call `cv::imread()` for files which are not PNG files - who cares what else `cv::imread()` would be able to decode?

Comment: Well... I do. It is not about to check whether an image is png-encoded or not, but to get a `cv::Mat` from it while it is already known that it is a png-image. However, the loading procedures provided by OpenCV I know always load code to decode other images than png-encoded ones. The code doing this seems to cause some trouble, so I want to call `cv::imread` but I can not since it's decoder overhead is a problem to the surrounding codebase. Or at least it seems so.

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue - could you explain please? Is there time or space issue that means you don't want other decoders loaded? It's hard to imagine there'd be space issues for a hundred kB of decoders if you are processing images, or that there'd be time issues. What's the actual problem, please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I put the reason for my question in my original post. Hopefully, this will make my question and it's motivation more clear.